# boost::context::basic_segmented_stack not growing on demand

Tags: c++, boost

I've got Boost 1.66, C++14, g++ 7.2.0, Ubuntu 16.04 on VM, Intel Core i5.

I'm using boost::fiber like in this example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/fiber/examples/segmented_stack.cpp.

Boost::fiber relays on boost::context, and I want to use boost::context::basic_segmented_stack as in the provided example.

I follow these instructions http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/stack/segmented.html

> ...Boost.Context must be built with property segmented-stacks, e.g.
>   toolset=gcc segmented-stacks=on and applying
>   BOOST_USE_SEGMENTED_STACKS at b2/bjam command line.

i.e. first run .*/bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=system,program_options,fiber,context ...*, then 
*./b2 toolset=gcc segmented-stacks=on ...*, and compile with *-DBOOST_USE_SEGMENTED_STACKS*.

However, the above example crashes at iteration 321:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:
>   SIGSEGV)

With basic_fixedsize_stack  it crashes at iteration 354.

But with basic_segmented_stack it should not crash as stack should grow on demand, right? So why does not it grow?

I also compiled with *-fsplit-stack*, but it's made no difference.
When I also run *b2* with property *context-impl=ucontext* and compile with *-BOOST_USE_UCONTEXT*, I got

> CMakeFiles/BContext.dir/main.cpp.o: In function
>   `boost::context::continuation::~continuation()':
>   /usr/local/include/boost/context/continuation_fcontext.hpp:229:
>   undefined reference to`ontop_fcontext'
>   CMakeFiles/BContext.dir/main.cpp.o: In function
>   `boost::context::continuation::resume()':
>   /usr/local/include/boost/context/continuation_fcontext.hpp:257:
>   undefined reference to`jump_fcontext'
>   CMakeFiles/BContext.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `void*
>   boost::context::detail::create_context2  ...

Answer (score 0):

```
b2 toolset=gcc segmented-stacks=on cxxflags="-DBOOST_USE_SEGMENTED_STACKS"
```

works for me